# EAV_ATTRIBUTE auto increment issue

Tags: magento2, attributes, eav-attributes, auto-increment

I am trying to save product attributes in my Magento2 system and there may be 100 thousands of attributes.

However, I see that the value specified as auto increment in the **eav_attribute** table is defined as **smallint**.

In this case, I get an error when I reach the value 65535 while saving these product attributes.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the data type for an existing column. You can create a new module and redefine the data type for it in `db_schema.xml` file.
In your case, we'll change the data type for the `attribute_id` column in the **eav_attribute** table from `small_int` (has a maximum value signed is 32767) to `int` (has a maximum value signed is 2147483647).

Assume the Vendor name is **TuVan** and the module name is **ChangeEAVAtrributeTableColumnType**, take the following steps:

Step 1: Create `app/code/TuVan/ChangeEAVAtrributeTableColumnType/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'TuVan_ChangeEAVAtrributeTableColumnType', __DIR__);
```

Step 2: Create `app/code/TuVan/ChangeEAVAtrributeTableColumnType/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TuVan_ChangeEAVAtrributeTableColumnType">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Eav"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create `app/code/TuVan/ChangeEAVAtrributeTableColumnType/etc/db_schema.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="eav_attribute">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="attribute_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true"
                comment="Attribute ID"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Step 4: Run the setup upgrade command to install and enable the module:

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Step 5: Run compilation code command:
`bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Step 6: Run deploy static content command:
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

You're done!

Since other tables also refer to the **eav_attribute** column, you'll need to find them and make the change for them as well.

You can run the following SQL query to [get all references for a database column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column).

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>' AND
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = '<table>' AND
  REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = '<column>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will this change work automatically for related tables that use the attribute_id field as a foreign key?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to say. Could you please provide more information or context?

Comment: For example some tables has foreign key eav_attribute.attribute_id. And these field type should be same. Will they all be updated when I make this change?

Comment: `magento.eav_entity_attribute.EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID` like this.

Comment: I understand your point, the answer is no, this change only applies to the **eav_attribute** table. Therefore, you should find all related tables that are referred to the **eav_attribute** column and make the change for them as well. I've updated my answer to add the SQL query to get all references for a database column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As far as I understood, I should do this every time. Because if I install 3rd party module and this module if it use eav_attribute.attribute_id field in foreign keys, I need to update this module field too. And it will not be useful I think. Am I wrong? What do you think?

Comment: Yes, that is right since 3rd party module usually use **small_int** like Magento core did.